# Host multiple pages in one page

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, youtube

I want to know How to have pages like YouTube's watch page, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc123 ?

I need it to do the following:

- when just going to the main file `watch.php`, I want it to :*show certain code for when they go to that page*,
- when they go to example `/watch?v=abc123`, I want it to : show different code only for that link.
- I also don't want the main `watch.php` page to be all cluttered up with code as I'll be at nearly 50+ times using these `?v=` I heard you can use Databases but I don't know.

Just whichever ones the best and easiest to make also please try and get it not to be clustered up and easy for me to edit. Thank you

Please Edit this if needed. [My website and page i'll be using](http://www.unfedzombie.com/watch)

Comment: That is just a prettied up URL with a parameter on the end of it.

Comment: But ? and = arent allowed on urls, I tought you had to use stuff like IF and ELSE statements but I dont want them it makes the main page looking all cluttered and a huge size with slow speed.

Comment: You're asking a lot without providing any work of your own. I would suggest starting with the basics of php and web development and spending a good amount of time reading.

Comment: I can't provide any work of my own as the only thing I have is the REALLY long HTML code I want the specific link to show.

Comment: You're missing my point, this isn't how stack overflow works. We all had to learn too and most of us did it by reading, not by going to sites and saying "I want this, and I want that, and make it easy for me". That's just crazy. Frankly, I don't understand why this hasn't been voted down already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only available via php. Using $_GET method.

Basically, the link is only www.mysite.com/watch.php. But if you use watch.php?v=123 then the $_GET['v'] will have the value of 123.

For more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

EDIT: basically your step would be like this

1. Set up a database. This depends on where you host your site. But most host service allow you to create and manage database.
2. Create a table with values you wanted to store.
3. Get the "v" value through $_GET
4. Run queries to connect to the database, and get the stored value. Ue echo to print it out on HTML

Comment: Ok i'll check out the link right now, give me a few minutes.

Comment: For a better answer, youtube use the $_GET to get the "v" value (which is video id), then run queries to get data from the database related to that id like video name, poster, how many like / dislike , etc etc. and display them. This is why big sites like news or video hosting like youtube can hold thousands of content without having thousands of php files for each of them.

Comment: No, It didn't seem to work it just creates code I want it to show specific html code I made once they go to example ?v=abc123

Comment: Aister how exactly could I do this? i have the GET set up with V but how exactly do I make these Databases and apply which HTML/PHP code to run on example /?v=abc123, Thanks. Try put it as an answer instead of a comment if you can.

Comment: That would be complicated depends on where you host your site. I've edited the answer with the general steps you need to take. You might want to look at mySQL queries, as well as how to connect to the database and retrieve values from it. There are lots of tutorials of these things on the internet so look it up.

Comment: Thank you so much Aister your helping me out alot, lol I just opened a question on how to import HTML code file using SRC saying using this until I learn how to use databases lol Thanks